# Prevent switching keyboard layout when pressing Shift+Space on an external keyboard

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, external-keyboard, text-input

When I use a Galaxy Note together with an Apple Wireless Keyboard, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> switches keyboard layout. This is really annoying. Is it possible to disable it?

Comment: Switches the Languages, you mean? 

You should be able to disable the language support, in settings, somewhere-- 

If not, try an alternate keyboard.

Comment: Yes, "switches the languages". I do not want do disable language support, I want several languages. I just do not like the crazy shortcut. I assume the keyboard shortcut is not a property of the keyboard but rather some Android built-in.
I assume there should be something like "setxkbmap" in normal Linux, which lets me tune those, but I have no clue where is the keyboard functionality hidden in Android.

Comment: Really? On my Galaxy Tab E, Ctrl-Space switches the keyboard layout (I have two: Japanese 109 and English (US)).  Shift-Space switches the input method, not the keyboard layout.

Comment: @Kaz perhaps nowadays things are different. I have a newer Lenovo tablet which does not have this problem now, for example.

Comment: @KT This problem is an issue of the Samsung Keyboard virtual keyboard.  Does your Lenovo tablet have some piece of software called "Samsung Keyboard"? If not, that's probably why it doesn't have the problem, not because it is newer.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue with the Samsung Galaxy S5 and a bluetooth keyboard. I was able to install Gboard (google keyboard from the app store) and this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I just got a Tab S7 with  Samsung's keyboard cover and this was annoying as heck. After reading this and seeing that the solution was just to download another keyboard, I knew there had to be a setting since you can't download a physical keyboard and case.

If you go to settings and search for "lang", then go to General Management > Language and Input > Physical Keyboard. Then go to "Change language shortcut. You can select which shortcut you use or turn it off entirely. I had three options and went with Ctrl + Space. Even though this is something I will probably never use.

Answer (score 3):

Switching to any other keyboard application as the default should solve this problem, for example SwiftKey. The shortcut exists in the Samsung keyboard and is not possible to turn off.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, unless there is a way to truly avoid Shift-Space triggering on Samsung keyboards (virtual or physical).

Answer (score 1):

On my Samsung phone running One UI version 3.1.1 and Android 11, this is a setting you can change in the following location:
Settings > General Management > Physical Keyboard* > Change language shortcut

In there are three (3) choices that will toggle between languages:

1. Shift + Space
2. Control + Space
3. Left Alt + Space

Simply move the slider to turn whichever options you want on or off.

---

*Physical keyboard must be connected to access this setting

Answer (score -3):

You can try ctrl+shift. This option better works for the XP. May be it can also work with you.

Comment: The OP isn't looking for the equivalent keyboard shortcut on Android - he already knows that it's Shift+Space. Now he's looking for how to *disable* that shortcut.