# Bluetooth keyboard keys are swapped

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard

I have a Samsung tablet and bought a cover with a Bluetooth keyboard. The problem I have is that the <kbd>@</kbd> key and the <kbd>"</kbd> key are swapped around.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

This can be due to a number of reasons:

1. You have a layout conflict between the OS and the Bluetooth keyboard, as pointed out by the previous answerer. Resolve this by going into the "Physical Keyboard Settings" option in the settings of whatever 3rd-party keyboard app you may have as default, or if you use the inbuilt soft keyboard, go into
   Settings -> Language and Input -> Keyboard app Settings button -> Input Layouts.
2. Same as above, but in this case the problem is due to a region setting in your phone which conflicts with the layout of the keyboard. Fix this by checking if the region setting on your tablet is incorrect for the keyboard layout, and correct as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem of the layout of the keyboard. Make sure that the layouts of keyboard on your OS and the Bluetooth keyboard consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I have Samsung Tab S7+ and my keys would change all the time. I knew it happened when I would use the <kbd>shift</kbd> key so I tried a bunch of combos. It ended up being <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space bar</kbd>. It makes sense it would happen often since I use these all the time.

I was using a Logitech K360 keyboard.

Comment: Note that Shift + Spacebar is usually [a shortcut to change IME/keyboard layout](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44848/44325).